# How to enable function routing with two different input topics

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am in the process of migrating an application to the new function based programming model of Spring Cloud Stream but block on event routing.

I have to route events coming from two different kafka topics, and I don't see how I can bind functionRouter-in-0 to two different destinations.

Routing would be done by adding a `spring.cloud.function.definition` header to each message on the producer side.

Let's say I have

- 4 consumer functions in my service : consumerA, consumerB, consumerC, consumerD
- 2 kafka topics :

  - topic1 that has messages with the spring.cloud.function.definition header having value consumerA or consumerB
  - topic2 that has message with the header having value consumerC or consumerD

How could I express in the configuration that the RoutingFunction.FUNCTION_NAME should listen to topic1 AND topic2 ?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function.definition: consumerA;consumerB;consumerC;consumerD
    stream:
      function.routing.enabled: true
      bindings:
        functionRouter-in-0:
          destination: topic1
          group: myService
          consumer:
            concurrency: 1
            partitioned: false
            maxAttempts: 1
        functionRouter-in-0:   # <== this oviously does not work because it's already defined above
          destination: topic2
          group: myService
          consumer:
            concurrency: 3
            maxAttempts: 1
```

Note : I'm on version 3.0.11.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to bindings nothing has changed from the annotation based model and as it is explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_programming_model) - "*If binding represents a consumer binding (input), it could be bound to multiple destinations, and the destination names can be specified as comma-separated String values.*"
So. . .

```
. . .
functionRouter-in-0:
          destination: topic1, topic2
          group: myService
. . .
```

The rest i believe is explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_event_routing), which discusses ROUTING TO and FROM as well as different mechanisms you can use - such as application property, message headers etc.

Also, for the outbound there are also several option you have.
One is [StreamBridge](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources) and [...sendto...](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_spring_cloud_stream_sendto_destination) header.

Feel free to follow up.

Comment: thanks, didn't catch that part in the doc sorry ! This could be a problem if you want different ConsumerProperties by destination though (concurrency or maxAttemps for example), no ? Is it possible to do that ? (it was possible with the StreamListeners)

Comment: also, it seems to me you can't mix "routed Consumers" with "non routed Consumers", as soon as I define a a function in property "spring.cloud.function.definition" routing doesn't work anymore, am I right ?

Comment: Yes, routing was made to be kind of a binary choice. The history behind it is to actually have a single function that will act as a gateway between the rest of the functions.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that s-c-stream is designed to facilitate "microservices" - do one thing but do it well. When one has many producers/consumers in a single app doing many different things, it is no longer a microservice, rather a basic messaging application and while you can still use s-c-stream it was not designed for that no we advocate it

Comment: Yes I understand, thanks for the follow up. Just to be sure, in the configuration you wrote there is no way to configure a different concurrency for topic1 and topic2, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct as you are effectively creating a single consumer to consume from several topics as if it was single.

Comment: Can you please mention the routing-expression for this scenario?