# Function routing with two input topics appears to break KafkaBinderMetrics

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/66871632/22992363 I am configuring a function router which accepts input from two Kafka topics. This is a cut-down copy of my configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      routing-expression: "headers['eventType']"
    stream:
      bindings:
        functionRouter-in-0:
          destination: order.requests,order.events
          binder: kafka
          content-type: application/json
          group: ${spring.application.name}-app
          consumer:
            concurrency: 12
            autoStartup: true
```

When the app starts, I get an exception:

```
2023-12-19 11:45:25.505 DEBUG [order-fulfilment-svc,,,] 21186 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.s.c.s.binder.kafka.KafkaBinderMetrics  : Cannot generate metric for topic: order.requests

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access. currentThread(name: pool-3-thread-1, id: 65) otherThread(id: 66)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:2551)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquireAndEnsureOpen(KafkaConsumer.java:2532)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(KafkaConsumer.java:1993)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(KafkaConsumer.java:1969)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaBinderMetrics.findTotalTopicGroupLag(KafkaBinderMetrics.java:204)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaBinderMetrics.computeUnconsumedMessages(KafkaBinderMetrics.java:189)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaBinderMetrics.lambda$bindTo$0(KafkaBinderMetrics.java:154)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I have tried resetting concurrency to 1 and that does not eliminate the problem.

Removing the second topic does make the exception go away.

I am using SCS 3.2.9 and spring-kafka 2.9.13.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I've looked into this a bit more, and it seems the KafkaBinderMetrics class creates a threadpool, with one thread for each topic.  It also creates a KafkaConsumer based on the group name.  Then each thread uses the same KafkaConsumer, hence why there's an exception because the two threads for my two topics are trying to use the same KafkaConsumer object.

Comment: Can anyone advise on this? Should I raise the bug on SCS github page?

Answer (score 0):

`KafkaBinderMetrics` call `KafkaMessageChannelBinder` every time a `BindingCreatedEvent` event is received. This event is [created](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/core/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java#L580) for each topic from `functionRouter-in-0`. In other words when processing `order.requests`, we run [`this.scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/KafkaBinderMetrics.java#L154) for the `order.requests` topic. When processing `order.events`, we run `this.scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay` for the `order.requests` topics (a new thread was created here) and `order.events`.

To summarize, the problem is that `KafkaBinderMetrics` takes the list of topics from `KafkaMessageChannelBinder` every time new topics are initialized. The more topics are initialized, the more of them there are in `KafkaMessageChannelBinder`.

There are 3 variants for solve problem:

- leave everything as it is - **cons**: a log entry that can be disabled
- disable metric counting - **cons**: no metrics
- override KafkaBinderMetrics

Issue on [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/995)

Disable metrics:

```
@Bean
public MeterFilter disableKafkaOffsetMetrics() {
    return MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith(KafkaBinderMetrics.OFFSET_LAG_METRIC_NAME);
}
```

Comment: I found it worked if I created separate function routers for each topic.  
  
But I did wonder whether it would be possible to refactor the creation of the Consumers so that they were in independent i.e. not re-used by the multiple threads.  
  
Disabling as per the issue on github you've linked to isn't really a description of the issue. I'd have thought this needs its own separate issue to permit having Kafka metrics for multi-topic bindings without getting concurrent modification exceptions?